# How do I compute the limit of a radical outside of a fraction?

Tags: limits, radicals, fractions, infinity

How do I compute this?

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\sqrt[3]{n^2+5}-\sqrt[3]{n^2+3}\right)$$

I tried multiplying it by the conjugate exactly as if it were in a fraction, but it didn’t quite work out, because you end up with a way bigger expression.

Arriving at the solution likely uses the sandwich theorem, but with two separate expressions. I find it to be quite the challenge.

Comment: Multiply by $\frac {(\sqrt[3]{n^2+5})^2 + (\sqrt[3]{n^2+5})(\sqrt[3]{n^2+3})+(\sqrt[3]{n^2+3})^2}{(\sqrt[3]{n^2+5})^2 + (\sqrt[3]{n^2+5})(\sqrt[3]{n^2+3})+(\sqrt[3]{n^2+3})^2} $

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\frac{\sqrt[3]{n² +5} \ - \ \sqrt[3]{n² + 3}}{1}\right)$$

Multiply numerator and denominator by 
$$\left(\sqrt[3]{n² +5}\right)^2+\left(\sqrt[3]{n² +5}\right)\left(\sqrt[3]{n² +3}\right)+\left(\sqrt[3]{n² +3}\right)^2$$
the fraction becomes
$$\frac{\left(\sqrt[3]{n² +5}-\sqrt[3]{n² + 3}\right)\left[\left(\sqrt[3]{n² +5}\right)^2+\left(\sqrt[3]{n² +5}\right)\left(\sqrt[3]{n² +3}\right)+\left(\sqrt[3]{n² +3}\right)^2\right]}{\left(\sqrt[3]{n² +5}\right)^2+\left(\sqrt[3]{n² +5}\right)\left(\sqrt[3]{n² +3}\right)+\left(\sqrt[3]{n² +3}\right)^2}$$
Recalling the identity $(a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2)=a^3+b^3$ we get
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{(n^2+5)-(n^2+3)}{\sqrt[3]{(n² +5)^2}+\sqrt[3]{(n² +5)(n^2+3)}+\sqrt[3]{(n² +3)^2}}=$$
$$=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{2}{\sqrt[3]{(n² +5)^2}+\sqrt[3]{(n² +5)(n^2+3)}+\sqrt[3]{(n² +3)^2}}=0$$
Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

HINT: use that $$a^3-b^3=(a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2)$$

Comment: I don't quite see how that's going to work with $$ a^{1/3} + b^{1/3} $$

Comment: @leroy let $a = \sqrt[3]{n^2+5}, b  = \sqrt[3]{n^2+3}$ and $(a-b) = \frac {2}{a^2 + ab + b^2}$

Comment: it is $$(a^{1/3}+b^{1/3})(a^{2/3}-(ab)^{1/3}+b^{2/3})$$

Answer (score 1):

Use *Taylor's formula* at order $1$ near $0$:
$$(1+u)^{\tfrac13}=1+\frac u3+o(u).$$
Your expression rewrites as
\begin{align}
\sqrt[3]{n² +5} \ - \ \sqrt[3]{n² + 3}&=n^{\tfrac23}\biggl[\biggl(1+\frac 5{n^2}\biggr)^{\tfrac13}-\biggl(1+\frac 3{n^2}\biggr)^{\tfrac13}\biggr]\\
&=n^{\tfrac23}\biggl[\biggl(1+\frac 5{3n^2}\biggr)-\biggl(1+\frac 3{3n^2}\biggr)+o\biggl(\frac1{n^2}\biggr)\biggr]\\
&=\frac 2{3n^{\tfrac43}}+o\Biggl(\frac1{n^{\tfrac43}}\Biggr)\to 0\quad\text{as}\enspace n\to \infty.
\end{align}